# Is it possible to create a azure VM without creating a cloudservice through RESTFUL API

Tags: java, rest, azure

I am able to create a cloud service and then using that cloud service, I have created a VM using the REST API in Azure.

In my case , created cloud service is getting displayed on the portal.

Query 1 : Is it possible to restrict this display of cloud service in the new portal

Query 2 : In the Azure portal we are able to create a VM without even creating a cloud service. Is it possible to achieve the same via API?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure Virtual Machines actually are contained within a Cloud Service.  In the portal, when creating a new VM, the VM is a single-instance within an implicit Cloud Service.  The single-instance VM doesn't show as a Cloud Service in the portal until multiple VMs are added (load-balancing), and then the Cloud Service will appear.

If you've created a VM via the REST API, I think you'll have a Cloud Serivce even though the Cloud Service may not appear in the portal.

In the end, a "Cloud Service" is effectively a container for instances - web role, worker role, or a Virtual Machine.  Marc Russinovich talks about this at about the 17 minute point in his TechEd NA 2012 talk - http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AZR209.

Comment: Put another way, the portal lies to you by hiding the cloud service, but it's always there.

Comment: Thanks mcollier. Currently i am creating a cloud service and then using that cloud service i am creating a vm. In this scenario , created cloud service is getting displayed on the portal. Is it possible to restrict this display in the portal.

Comment: If you mean you want to hide that cloud service and not include in the list of cloud services displayed, then the answer is No. Just out of curiosity, why do you want to hide this cloud service?

Comment: Hi Gaurav, when i create a vm from portal , associated implicit cloud services is not getting appeared in the portal . Same kind of behavior i just want to maintain even for vm creation thru REST call..

Comment: Actually what I noticed is that they don't appear immediately after I create a VM. If I fetch the list of cloud services after say 15 - 30 minutes, I can see those cloud services. Portal uses the same Service Management REST API.

Comment: Gaurav, my doubt is , similar to portal , is it possible to create a STANDALONE VM thru REST API ? thanks...

Answer (score -2):

If you mean "vm eqauls VERTUAL MACHINBES", you can use Azure Command-Line Tools.It's created as  node.js 
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/